# can't import GoogleMaps in python

Tags: python, linux

I'm new to Python and also new to Linux. I want to know why this code doesn't work?

```
(gmapenv)teruun@ubuntu:~/gmapenv$ python -c 'import googlemaps'
(gmapenv)teruun@ubuntu:~/gmapenv$ from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
```

and it says:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/googlemaps
```

what does this mean? what does `from: can't read` mean?

Comment: The first line apparently works. With the second line you are trying to execute Python code in bash, which naturally fails. ``from`` in bash has nothing to do with ``from`` in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install whatever Python libraries using e.g. `pip` or `easy_install` before you can import the `googlemaps` module in your Python code. This is because there is no GoogleMaps library that is built in to the Python standard library. I see you've already gotten started with using virtualenv, which is good. Also, perhaps you already installed a library, but maybe you installed the wrong one, or you installed it globally and then created a virtualenv, which by default is isolated from your globally installed packages. So either create a non-isolated virtualenv (not recommended) or install the package into the virtualenv (and uninstall globally).

Also, the second line you posted attempts to execute Python code directly on Bash, which doesn't work for obvious reasons, and gives a cryptic error message because Bash thinks you're expecting it to be a Bash command, and it just so happens that `from` actually is a command.

Comment: Thanks for helping. And I did as you said. But it's still going wrong. Here is what I typed and the error messages. I just can't get what's going wrong.(gmapenv)teruun@ubuntu:~/gmapenv$ pip install googlemaps
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): googlemaps in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
(gmapenv)teruun@ubuntu:~/gmapenv$ python -c 'import googlemaps'
(gmapenv)teruun@ubuntu:~/gmapenv$ python search1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print GoogleMaps().address_to_latlng(address)

Comment: Code in the search1.py is this

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
# Foundations of Python Network Programming
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
address = '207 N. Defiance St, Archbold, OH'
print GoogleMaps().address_to_latlng(address)

Comment: So your `ImportError` was fixed, I can see. If you have further problems which you feel you cannot solve on your own, feel free to open another question perhaps. Also, if my answer solved the problem you mentioned in the question, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: P.S. it's quite terrible to have to read multi-line console output snippets in comments, especially if you've cut off the most important part of the traceback, the error message.

Comment: No,it's not solved. But still thanks for helping. I created a new enviorenment and installed the library but it still doesn't work. And my english is not so good to express well.

Comment: And can I get your email address and send the picture for you ?

Comment: Please just read a Python tutorial/book first. I'm sure with basic Python skill, you can solve your basic problems independently.